# Why does all of my text appear in the same place

Tags: html, css

Well im trying to achieve a basic effect of 6 images placed next to each other ( 2 rows of 3) and want to add some text over them. But the problem is (I think) in the float = left "command" in the CSS, which indeed puts my images nicely next to each other... BUT throws all of my text in the one place instead of nicely with the appropriate image. I've been sitting and thinking on this for solid few days and have no idea what to do. Hope you can help.

CSS

```
.text {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    color: black;
    width: 100%;
}

.image {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    padding: 2px;
    position: relative;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="row" style="width:1600px">
        <div class="container">
            <img class="image" src="Life.jpg" alt="Life" style="width:520px;height:360px;"  />
            <p class="text">Life</p>
        </div>

        <div  class="container">
            <img class="image" src="Trees are Cool.jpg" alt="Trees Are Cool" style="width:520px;height:360px;"  />
            <p class="text">Trees are Cool</p>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <img class="image" src="Radical dinosaurs.jpg" alt="Radical Dino" style="width:520px;height:360px;" />
            <p class="text">Radical Dinosaurs</p>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <img class="image" src="Big Round Vuttons.jpg" alt="Big Round Buttons" style="width:520px;height:360px;"/>
            <p class="text">Big Round Buttons</p>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <img class="image" src="Run.jpg" alt="Run" style="width:520px;height:360px;"/>
            <p class="text">Run</p>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <img class="image" src="Thats crazy.jpg" alt="That's Crazy" style="width:520px;height:360px;"/>
            <p class="text">That's Crazy</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: don't you think. you should create a fiddle demo

Comment: see this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nk3h6n0a/)

Comment: Ok, now see my Fiddle   https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/oLLos5yr/16/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that you are positioning your image to relative. but your `.text` is direct child of `.container` by default `.text` find it's parent to be position relative but `.container` has not apply css property position relative then it find `.container` parent to be position relative and so on, in the end html is position relative that's why all your code stack on the top of each other.

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Arif_Iqbal/hdpbc0ud/)

try this

```
.contailer{
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: @Mar if my answer is helpful for you, you should consider it as check answer. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use following css, this will solve your problem

```
   .text {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 100;
        color: black;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;

    }

.container {
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 2px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: relative` to the .container class, so it will be the .text element context. The element is positioned in relation to the context.

The context is the last parent that has position: relative / absolute / fixed. Right now the context is probably some higher level container or even the body itself, so all .text items are concentrated there.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the position of the elements like other have pointed out

```
.text {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    color: black;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
}

.image {
    padding: 2px;
    position: relative;
}
.container {
    float:left;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xqf8kfd1/1/

Answer (score 0):

Give 'container' class style as follows:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}
```

And remove `float: left;` from 'image' class

Answer (score -1):

try removing the position:absolute and adding float:left to the css text class

```
.text {
float: left;
z-index: 100;
color: black;
width: 100%;
display: inline-block;
```

}